What happens if append-only database crash during append?
In the book "Designing Data Intensive Applications", it says

Concurrency and crash recovery are simpler if segment files are
append-only or immutable. For crash recovery, you don't need to worry
if a crash happened while a value was being overwritten, leaving you
with part of old data and part of new data.

But what if we crash while appending? Wouldn't it leave the segment file with only part of the data we intend to append? Do they use a checksum on the segment file and discard the whole segment file?

Are you familiar with write-ahead-logging?

@Dai no, thanks for that, I just looked and it seems like it can reduce the chance of corruption happening, but if we crash while writing to the log, we will still get the same problem.

"we will still get the same problem." - on the contrary: if a crash happens during the final log write then the log-write won't be persisted, which means the entire txn will be discarded. If a crash happens a nanosecond after the final log write is persisted then that's perfectly fine too because the last write still succeeded.

Oh, I see, I see, the transaction will fail, and the user (or database) will get to decide whether to retry or not. Thanks!

Well, yes - but may I ask what possible alternative you had in-mind?

@weilueluo write-ahead log is itself essentially an append-only database which is periodically used to update the main regular database and then discarded.

@weilueluo And the atomicity of appends to WAL is achieved as I describe in by answer.

Actually no, I don't really have a alternative, should have thought of it earlier haha

Commonly used filesystems guarantee that file byte ranges not being written to are not going to be affected by the write in any circumstance (aside from bugs and hardware faults). So you can checksum each transaction separately, and on crash
recovery discard only transactions after the first partially written one by truncating the segment file.

How would such a system know that any given transaction was only partially written or not, though?

@Dai by checking the transaction checksum. If it doesn't match, the write was not completed.

So commonly used filesystem guarantee append is atomic? Even if we append a very large amount of data?

@weilueluo no, that's not the case. What I'm saying is that you can include the transaction checksum in the transaction. You don't just append the transaction_data to the file, you append a record of the form checksum(transaction_data) + transaction_data. Either this append completes fully and the written checksum matches the data, or it doesn't and they don't match. When recovering after crash you walk the file and look for the first record where the checksum doesn't match the data, and discard it and everything afterwards.

I see, yea makes sense, so we will only lose the last failed data, instead of the whole file, thanks!
